# "#" (aka pound) character in server path

Tags: excel, server, path

Win 10, Excel 2013 (32-bit) - Hyperlink and/or Hyperlink Function

Established file server (not under my control) has some folders with the pound character in the path, e.g., \server\folder1\#___someCompany\someTopic.

I'm trying to create hyperlink to the someTopic folder. Hard coding UNC path via set Hyperlink did not work correctly. Windows opens Explorer at folder1 level. Similarly, Excel's Hyperlink Function produces the same result.

Interestingly, manually navigating thru the folder structure using Explorer yields no issues. Also, copying and pasting the entire UNC path into Explorer also works as expected.

I've tried to escape the # character with slash or backtick to no avail.
I've tried to encapsulate the entire UNC path in " using the cell Hyperlink or the Excel Hyperlink function both to no avail.

Evidence suggests that it is an Excel implementation limitation.

Workaround?

Comment: `Workaround?` - reading [the docs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Reserved_characters)?

Answer (score 0):

TY, that is indeed part of the solution. However, there is also some noteworthy granularity here.

**Cell-based Hyperlink**:
After tinkering, I found that reversing the folder separator characters, swapping "\" with "/", worked as-is without having to employ the percent-based escape sequence "%23" for "#".

The same cannot be said for the **Hyperlink Function** however. It's behavior is different.
Swapping folder delimiter characters only results in the previously unwanted result.
Swapping folder delimiter characters AND employing the percent-based escape sequence does produce the desired Explorer result.

For completeness, attempts to utilize hyperlinks that employed only the percent-based escape sequence resulted in Excel declaring an error.

TY and I hope this helps anyone else who encounters this or related issues.

Answer (score 0):

I found a (slightly intensive) workaround that utilizes VBA and the Shell function.

This method is tested true to work on a Windows 10 computer with Windows File Explorer. Any adjustments needed to utilize the work around in other OS environments is not considered.

This also does NOT work with the `=HYPERLINK` worksheet function.

General overview:

1. Create Dummy Hyperlink
2. Create "FollowHyperLink" Private Sub
3. Have VBA code open the appropriate folder/file with "#" in the path name

**Step 1: Make a dummy Hyperlink**

The purpose here is to have something clickable that looks familiar to the user, rather than a typical Macro Button. Creating this can either be done manually or via VBA code itself.

Manually:

1. Right-click cell and choose "Link"
2. On the dialog, enter the Text you want to display (i.e. Open Folder)
3. Then, for the Address reference of the hyperlink, have it reference the file you have open. -- This causes the hyperlink to "open itself", and the end result is it just does nothing on the surface

Via VBA: See [Hyperlinks.Add Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Hyperlinks.Add)

**Step 2: Create VBA code triggered by clicking a Hyperlink**

If you've never ventured into Visual Basic for Applications (VBA), then strap in! If not, Open Visual Basic window and skip the section below.

To access VBA, you'll need the "Developer" tab on your ribbon.

- File > Options > Customize Ribbon
- Right section, check mark the box next to "Developer", and click "OK"
- Click the "Developer" Tab, and on the far left, click "Visual Basic"

Within the VBA window, expand the file tree on the left. Open "Microsoft Excel Objects", and select the excel sheet that will have the Hyperlink in it (in my instance, "Sheet1")

In the right-side section, change the top Left dropdown to "Worksheet", and the Right dropdown to "FollowHyperlink". This will create a Private Sub similar to below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

End Sub
```

Anything within this sub will happen when any hyperlink on the excel sheet is clicked. Ideally, we'd add code into here to ascertain information from the Excel file to determine what our actual Hyperlink path is that contains the Pound (#) symbol.

**Step 3: VBA code to Open Folder/File with "#" in the Path name.**

The pivotal point here is utilizing the Shell function to open Windows File Explorer, thereby bypassing the use of any built-in Excel Hyperlink functions.
The general syntax is as follows:

`Shell "Explorer.exe " & PathStr, vbNormalFocus`

Where "PathStr" is a string variable containing the text to your folder/file. My particular code is to open a Folder, hence most references are to a Path, not a File.

**Below is my code simply as an example** of how I take information from the cell the Hyperlink is in (specifically the Row of the worksheet), and then obtain other text information from the worksheet itself ("Job" and "PCO") to create my Path String. *"ProjectsPath" and "COsPCOsPath" are public string constants (aka predefined text not part of the Subroutine), and "OvJobC" and "OvPCONumC" are public integer constants (aka predefined numerical values).*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Job As String
Dim PCO As String
Dim Rw As Integer
Dim PathStr As String

Rw = Target.Range.Row 'Get Hyperlink Row
Set WS = Target.Range.Worksheet 'Define the Worksheet
With WS
    Job = .Cells(Rw, OvJobC) 'Obtain Text from Cell
    PCO = .Cells(Rw, OvPCONumC) 'Obtain Text from Cell
End With

PathStr = ProjectsPath & "\" & Job + COsPCOsPath & "\PCO#" & PCO 'Create Path String with "#"

Shell "Explorer.exe " & PathStr, vbNormalFocus 'And, Open it

End Sub
```

And there you have it. One heck of a workaround to have an in-cell hyperlink open any file or folder with the pesky "#" symbol contained within it.

I feel very accomplished. I hope this helps someone else.